# Protect by login files uploaded with rails carreirwave 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, carrierwave

I want to protect the uploaded files, they remain in the public/upload directory and are accessible so the user is not logged in as follows `http://localhost:3000/uploads/video/1/test.mp4`. I want to prevent that happening, that the user to see the contents is logged on and can see the video if and only if it has permissions to see it

My application is that a user has a workshop and this workshops have many sessions, each of these sessions has a video. Here I leave the content of my models`**enter code here**`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable,
         :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :workshop

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  enum role: [:student, :teacher]

end

class Workshop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sessions
  has_many :users

  validates :name, presence: true
end

class Session < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :workshop

  mount_uploader :video, WsvideoUploader

  before_create :default_name

  def default_name
    self.video ||= File.basename(video.filename, '.*').titleize if video
  end

end
```

Currently the files are stored in the default route of carrierwave, I leave them the code of the class that inherits from carrierwave.

```
class WsvideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller actions can be protected to be called by authenticated users by using before_filter. But since accessing carrierwave-uploaded files does not invoke any controller action, you cannot use a before_filter, not in a straightforward way anyway. 
In order to do what you want to do, **you need to save the uploaded files in a directory not under public and then use a controller to access the file**.

Since you are using Devise, you can add authentication to actions in controller by simply adding `before_action :authenticate_user!`

A more detailed explanation is given on Carrierwave Wiki page. You can find it here [secure-upload-using-carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/how-to:-secure-upload)